# Multiline logs promtail grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

Hi I am trying to do multiline logging using promtail and grafana so that I can have stack traces as well. My logs are in json format and look like

```
{"log": "event=\"Unhandled exception\" exception=\"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \\\"<string>\\\", line 3, in <module>\nException: Bad Code\" level=error timestamp=2023-12-11T11:53:45.720646Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:53:45.720646Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Peek BatchJob\" level=info timestamp=2023-12-11T11:53:50.725929Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:53:50.725929Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Peek BatchJob\" level=info timestamp=2023-12-11T11:53:55.731382Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:53:55.731382Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Peek BatchJob\" level=info timestamp=2023-12-11T11:54:00.734867Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:54:00.734867Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Peek BatchJob\" level=info timestamp=2023-12-11T11:54:05.738426Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:54:05.738426Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Unhandled exception\" exception=\"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/Users/nischalsehrawat/Desktop/my_test/test_file_loggin.py\", line 53, in <module>\n    exception_raise2()\n  File \"/Users/nischalsehrawat/Desktop/my_test/test_file_loggin.py\", line 48, in exception_raise2\n    raise ValueError(\"This is a value error\")\nValueError: This is a value error\" level=error timestamp=2023-12-11T11:54:10.741244Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:54:10.741244Z"}
{"log": "event=\"Peek BatchJob\" level=info timestamp=2023-12-11T11:54:15.742902Z\n", "stream": "stdout", "attrs": {"tag": "sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|dispatcher|sha256:3c58cfee6a3cdccad1865604fe8652f76471024deb52d654588bed3114e40d5b|c7c5deb744890510e981843cc00f7bab29976a9dcb313147d7f453ef8faeb616"}, "time": "2023-12-11T11:54:15.742902Z"}
```

and my promtail config looks like

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: system
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: varlogs
          __path__: /var/log/*log
    pipeline_stages:
      - json:
          expressions:
            output: log
            stream: stream
            attrs:
      - json:
          expressions:
            tag:
          source: attrs
      - regex:
          expression: '(?P<image_name>[^|]+)\\.(?P<container_name>[^|]+)\\.(?P<image_id>[^|]+)\\.(?P<container_id>[^|]+)'
          source: tag
      - timestamp:
          format: RFC3339Nano
          source: time
      - labels:
          tag:
          stream:
          image_name:
          container_name:
          image_id:
          container_id:
      - output:
          source: output
```

So in `event=Unhandled exception` there is traceback in `exception` which is multiline. And this is how my logs look in grafana

[image]

The logs with tracebacks are being shown correctly as one single log entry. My question is why is this the case. How is this working correctly without doing any multiline processing ?

I could find something [in this post](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/74#issuecomment-464757811) but I am not sure if this is what explains it.

Comment: Are you sure those are multiline? Because right now all I see are a bunch of jsons, that contain `\n` literally.

Comment: @markalex probably what I wanted to ask was how will the exception key be treated here since it has a bunch of `\n` characters. Do I need to do some multiline parsing ? or will this entrire line be treated as one ?

Comment: AFAICT, your log is single line. Newlines of stacktrace are converted to `\n` when it's placed into json, and back once json is parsed. So no additional considerations are required.